# Fancybox wont load after load function till second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

So my problem is that fancybox wont work till 2nd click :/ i have no idea why :/ i added a live event but still nothing its really weird.

heres my code

galeria is running on the document ready function

```
function galeria() {
$("#content").load(Lugar +'/Galeria #content',function() {
    $(".inscripciones").css('color', '#90D3CB');
    $(".nosotros").css('color', '#90D3CB');
    $(".programas").css('color', '#90D3CB');
    $(".servicios").css('color', '#90D3CB');
    $(".inicio").css('color', '#90D3CB');
    $(".noticias").css('color', '#90D3CB');
    $(".contacto").css('color', '#90D3CB');
    $(".galeria").css('color', '#FCF8F6');
    $("#cargaContenido").html("");
    $(".caja p a").attr('rel', 'cajita')
     $( '.container' ).children().show();
     $(".Portafolio").addClass('oversubmenu')
        $("#loader").hide();


        columnas();
    hoverli();
        focusli();
        taller();
         instalaciones();
         portafolio();

         hovernav();
         siguientebloque();
         antesbloque();
    box();

});
```

}

```
function box(){

$(".caja p a").attr("rel","cajita").live('click', function() {
  /*$this = $(this);
    $.fancybox({

        href: $this.attr('href'),

    });*/
   $(".caja p a").attr("rel","cajita").fancybox({

    });
    return false;
});
}
```

Comment: It would help to see your html that you are trying to use fancybox on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to assign the handler to the link with attribute `rel="cajita"`?  What you are really doing is assigning that attribute to the link.

And why are you calling your fancybox in a click handler?  Fancybox should apply the click handler for you:

```
function box() {

    $(".caja p a").fancybox({});

}
```

This will probably fix your problem.

Comment: fancybox galleries need to have the same rel to work actually i saw that on the fancybox trick stuff, btw i tried this but still nothing :/

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to assign it when they click, too.  You are already assigning it when you attach the handler.

Comment: oh kk tnx you have any idea why my fancybox is not loading? weird huh?

Comment: Well, for one thing, why are you applying your fancybox in a click handler?

Comment: LOL it worked that way srry i usually bind everything to a click event tnx a bunch bro!